# Show a popup when clicking the upvote button on already upvoted comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-voting, popups

When you try to revote or retract your vote for a post (answer or question) you see the following message:

> [image: vote is locked]

But there is no notification about the same actions on comments, only a tooltip:

> [image: comments]

Please add such a popup for comment upvotes too, saying when we upvoted and explaining how we can't undo the vote anymore.

Comment: No change. It let you undo the comment upvote for few minutes, unless you reload the page (even few seconds after voting) then you can't undo it. (There was never any popup showing when clicking the comment upvote indicator.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard hence I'll add [feature-request] tag :)